# PHP PDOStatement::fetchAll returned array contains resource?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

i'm getting data out of a oracle database:

My code is really simple

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($data);
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

PHP gives me a resource ID for very long strings in $res.

**I want them as a string not a resource ID.**

So i can set

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, true);
```

But now all values are Strings. Not just the resource ones.

Is there a way to achieve this?

(Yes i know that resource IDs are maybe better, but i want it as a string in this case)

Comment: Can you please share what is `resource ID` ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer it's a regular PHP's file handle

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: With [`PDOStatement::bindColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) you can specify the type of the column. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your response ishegg. Maybe i should have given more information: I want this automatically without giving the explicit column name

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is to use native drivers like PHP OCI8 instead of the limited PHP PDO interface.  With OCI8 you can do things like:

```
while (($arr = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC))) {
    $arr = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS);
    echo $arr['BLOBDATA'];   // do something with the LOB
    unset($arr);             // free PHP's memory before fetching the next LOB.
}
```

Check out the PHP manual pages or the LOB chapter http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html